MassTransit RateLimit with multiple consumers on one queue
I'm looking for clarification on how the UseRateLimit(...) functionality works in the following situation where we have many consumers sharing the same queue. Each consumer has it's own unique message type and this is only for a single service (i.e. no competing consumers / distributed processing).
enter image description here
My question is, will this limit the overall message consumption rate for the entire queue to 10 per second, or will it limit each consumer to 10 per second? The goal here is to use UseRateLimit(...) to adhere to a rate limit set by a third party API which all the listed consumers use.
I'm asking on behalf of another dev, who has given some conflicting reports of how it is behaving. With UseRateLimit(10, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) I would expect that the total consumption rate for the entire queue would be limited to ten messages per second, but wondering if my assumption on the behavior is incorrect.

Order matters, and the filter is being configured after all the consumers, so, it wouldn't be applied.
Also, ConfigureConsumer<T>(context) should be used, not Consumer<T>(context).
